# Where is this symbol coming from? CSS

Tags: css

I was studying the `::before` on the Mozilla developer website and I was playing with this example on codepen:

https://codepen.io/levisn1/pen/oaEPEN

```js
var list = document.querySelector('ul');
list.addEventListener('click', function(ev) {
  if (ev.target.tagName === 'LI') {
    ev.target.classList.toggle('done');
  }
}, false);
```

```css
li {
  list-style-type: none;
  position: relative;
  margin: 2px;
  padding: 0.5em 0.5em 0.5em 2em;
  background: lightgrey;
  font-family: sans-serif;
}

li.done {
  background: #CCFF99;
}

li.done::before {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  border-color: #009933;
  border-style: solid;
  border-width: 0 0.3em 0.25em 0;
  height: 1em;
  top: 1.3em;
  left: 0.6em;
  margin-top: -1em;
  transform: rotate(45deg);
  width: 0.5em;
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li>Buy milk</li>
  <li>Take the dog for a walk</li>
  <li>Exercise</li>
  <li>Write code</li>
  <li>Play music</li>
  <li>Relax</li>
</ul>
```

I don't understand where is the green symbol V coming from when I click on an element of the list.  Is it a special symbol related to the `class="done"` class appended to a `li` tag?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here, it's just a fat border rotated 45 degrees, pretty clever actually (remove the rotate to see what I mean):

```
li.done::before {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  border-color: #009933;
  border-style: solid;
  border-width: 0 0.3em 0.25em 0;
  height: 1em;
  top: 1.3em;
  left: 0.6em;
  margin-top: -1em;
  transform: rotate(45deg);
  width: 0.5em;
}
```

Comment: Yeah, i figured out now, i started to study css not long ago and it surprised me. Thank You!

Answer (score 1):

it's not a symbol, it's just a block element rotated by 45 degrees

Comment: I didn't know you could styling these pseudo-elements and give them new shapes. Thank you!